# Submit webform via POST on restful API

Tags: webforms, services

I'm trying to submit JSON data directly to a webform through some restful resource. My thought was to create a webform, enable webform_service, and then post directly to the endpoint. This lead me to try something like this:

```
curl -vv -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"Contact Us", "submitted[contact_fullname]": "my name", "submitted[contact_email]": "test@example.com", "submitted[contact_message]": "test message"}' http://localhost/api/contact_us.json
```

But this does not work. In fact without the "title" value I get "title field is required", which seems to be trying to create a new webform, and in fact if I provide a title, a new webform is, in fact, created. But this is not what I'm looking to do - I'm trying to submit a new entry into the existing webform.

I thought that perhaps there's a different resource that I should be submitting form data to:

```
curl -vv -X POST -d 'submitted[contact_fullname]=sundartest&submitted[contact_email]=test@lp.com&submitted[contact_message]=test_message' http://ike.localhost/api/contact_emc.submission
```

But obviously this is wrong and I'm just guessing!

Any pointers on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: The documentation for Webform Services is pretty much non existent. I posted a comment outlining how to submit a Webform via POST with the Webform Services module here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1569772#comment-9011749

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/763010/tyler-frankenstein created a grate article that can be found [here](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile)

you might also find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428014/steps-to-make-a-mobile-application-using-drupal-as-a-back-end-or-service/13662041#13662041 useful it has links to articles that describe services in full.

I'd also advise a couple plugins
Firefox: [poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/)
Chrome: [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)

http://drupal.org/node/1795770 might be more applicable it's how to login, post a comment, and loggout from curl hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the best solution was http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6523/submit-webform-programatically-in-drupal-7. I also found that I *must* do an ajax post, and not just JSON.

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment previously, I'm just closing this with the solution that worked for me:

[How to submit webform programmatically with Ajax?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6523/submit-webform-programatically-in-drupal-7). It must be done with as an AJAX POST with JSON data, rather than form data.