# Creating webform submissions programatically in order to use with SimpleTest

Tags: webforms, forms, testing

I'm trying to build out a SimpleTest to test out functionality on **submitted webforms**. I need to simulate loading a drupal webform node, applying fake data, and submitting the form (triggering a database save).

Currently, I'm forcing data in (on a vagrant box) a drupal instance, but I have a feeling there is a better way to do this.

**Question:** 
In Simpletest, how do I properly load a webform, inject fake data into the form fields, and submit the form?

**First attemtp:** 
Original fixture code. It works, but it's sloppy!

```
Class myTest extends DrupalWebTestCase {
.
.
.
  /*
  Drops ALL DATA in the tables being tested
  */
  function _dropData() {
     db_query('delete from {webform_submitted_data}');
     db_query('delete from {webform_submissions}');
  }

  /*
  Fixtures, test data. Clears both webform_submitted_data and webform_submissions
  and then adds a new set of mock data generated initially by a browser plugin
  that autofills forms. This allows for a standardized set of data used on the
  simple test form (import script included in the package).
  */
  function _populateTablesWithTestData() {
    $q1 = "SET SQL_MODE = \"NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO\"; INSERT INTO `webform_submitted_data` (`nid`, `sid`, `cid`, `no`, `data`) VALUES (1, 59, 2, '0', 'Dignissimos enim dolorem quia et minim velit eiusmod eiusmod voluptas nemo nostrum cum aliquam unde mollit obcaecati'), (1, 59, 3, '0', 'pugy@example.com'), (1, 59, 4, '0', '2013-03-11'), (1, 60, 2, '0', 'Sapiente velit voluptatem et quod et proident voluptatem Sunt minima reprehenderit reprehenderit'),(1, 60, 3, '0', 'nejemuno@example.com'),(1, 60, 4, '0', '2014-05-16'),(1, 61, 2, '0', 'Id nisi pariatur Quidem in nihil culpa qui rerum minim nihil ea minim ipsa fugiat'),(1, 61, 3, '0', 'mohafowoba@example.com'),(1, 61, 4, '0', '2015-05-02'),(1, 62, 2, '0', 'Omnis quisquam nisi non et est est eiusmod qui qui odio ut dignissimos'),(1, 62, 3, '0', 'vujil@example.com'),(1, 62, 4, '0', '2015-03-02');";
    $q2 = "SET SQL_MODE = \"NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO\"; INSERT INTO `webform_submissions` (`sid`, `nid`, `serial`, `uid`, `is_draft`, `submitted`, `remote_addr`) VALUES (59, 1, 59, 0, 0, 1424275998, '192.168.33.1'), (60, 1, 60, 0, 0, 1424276006, '192.168.33.1'), (61, 1, 61, 0, 0, 1424276013, '192.168.33.1'), (62, 1, 62, 0, 0, 1424276031, '192.168.33.1');";

    $this->_dropData();
    db_query($q1);
    db_query($q2);
  }
```

**Second Attempt:**

In a test script to be run from drush...

```
$form_state = array();
$form_state['values']['test2']='Something';
$form_state['values']['test_email']='Some@email.ext';
$form_state['values']['test_date']="";

drupal_form_submit('webform_client_form_1', $form_state);
```

However, this gives me:

```
$ drush scr test.php

Missing argument 3 for webform_client_form() webform.module:2268                                                               [warning]
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() webform.module:2843
```

**Third Attempt**

```
$form_state = array();
$form_state['values']['test2']='Something';
$form_state['values']['test_email']='Some@email.ext';
$form_state['values']['test_date']="";
$form_state['op'] = t('Submit');


drupal_form_submit('webform_client_form_1', $form_state, node_load(1), array());
print_r(form_get_errors());
```

Which gets:

```
$drush scr test.php

end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given webform.module:3120                                                          [warning]
end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given webform.module:3123
```

**What the form looks like**

Export Code:

```
$webform = array (
  'nid' => '1',
  'next_serial' => '63',
  'confirmation' => '',
  'confirmation_format' => 'filtered_html',
  'redirect_url' => '<confirmation>',
  'status' => '1',
  'block' => '0',
  'allow_draft' => '0',
  'auto_save' => '0',
  'submit_notice' => '1',
  'submit_text' => '',
  'submit_limit' => '-1',
  'submit_interval' => '-1',
  'total_submit_limit' => '-1',
  'total_submit_interval' => '-1',
  'progressbar_bar' => '1',
  'progressbar_page_number' => '0',
  'progressbar_percent' => '0',
  'progressbar_pagebreak_labels' => '1',
  'progressbar_include_confirmation' => '1',
  'progressbar_label_first' => 'Start',
  'progressbar_label_confirmation' => 'Complete',
  'preview' => '0',
  'preview_next_button_label' => '',
  'preview_prev_button_label' => '',
  'preview_title' => '',
  'preview_message' => '',
  'preview_message_format' => 'filtered_html',
  'preview_excluded_components' => 
  array (
  ),
  'record_exists' => true,
  'roles' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
  ),
  'emails' => 
  array (
  ),
  'components' => 
  array (
    2 => 
    array (
      'nid' => 1,
      'cid' => '2',
      'pid' => '0',
      'form_key' => 'test2',
      'name' => 'TEST Text ',
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'value' => '',
      'extra' => 
      array (
        'title_display' => 'before',
        'private' => 0,
        'wrapper_classes' => '',
        'css_classes' => '',
        'width' => '',
        'maxlength' => '',
        'field_prefix' => '',
        'field_suffix' => '',
        'disabled' => 0,
        'unique' => 0,
        'description' => '',
        'placeholder' => '',
        'attributes' => 
        array (
        ),
        'analysis' => false,
      ),
      'required' => '0',
      'weight' => '1',
      'page_num' => 1,
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'nid' => 1,
      'cid' => '3',
      'pid' => '0',
      'form_key' => 'test_email',
      'name' => 'TEst Email',
      'type' => 'email',
      'value' => '',
      'extra' => 
      array (
        'title_display' => 'before',
        'private' => 0,
        'wrapper_classes' => '',
        'css_classes' => '',
        'width' => '',
        'unique' => 0,
        'disabled' => 0,
        'description' => '',
        'placeholder' => '',
        'attributes' => 
        array (
        ),
        'analysis' => false,
      ),
      'required' => '0',
      'weight' => '2',
      'page_num' => 1,
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'nid' => 1,
      'cid' => '4',
      'pid' => '0',
      'form_key' => 'date',
      'name' => 'Date',
      'type' => 'date',
      'value' => '',
      'extra' => 
      array (
        'title_display' => 'before',
        'private' => 0,
        'wrapper_classes' => '',
        'timezone' => 'user',
        'start_date' => '-2 years',
        'end_date' => '+2 years',
        'year_textfield' => 0,
        'datepicker' => 1,
        'description' => '',
        'analysis' => false,
      ),
      'required' => '0',
      'weight' => '4',
      'page_num' => 1,
    ),
  ),
  'conditionals' => 
  array (
  ),
);
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: For building automated tests you should used [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: For front end, yes. However, I need to test specific actions *inside the database*. This is also an exercise in learning how to properly set up a SimpleTest in Drupal for module development.

Comment: Have you hear about the Coder module ?

Comment: I've used Coder, which is great at syntax checking and best practices in coding convention. My real hope is to learn how to create webform content in order to use in server side automated testing.

Comment: I know that you're question is related to SimpleTest. You could also give behat testing a shot. You can fill in forms and submitted them following the steps(clicking etc) and actual user would do.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21simpletest%21drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3A%3AdrupalPost/7

Comment: Notice that webform module itself contains tests for form submission. You can use them as an example.

Comment: @PotneySwitters, I'm unfamiliar with that option? Can you throw a good link up?

Comment: You can find a good installation guide here : http://behat-drupal-extension.readthedocs.org/en/latest/globalinstall.html Some basic explanation here: http://kevinquillen.com/bdd/2014/06/08/your-first-behat-test/ And a nice project to check out here: https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension

Comment: Thanks @PotneySwitters, while @web-spider answer below got it working in the context of `drush scr`, porting into SimpleTest has been a nightmare. I will definitely check this out. In fact a local camp has a session on this I believe soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically submit a webform, you can use the following code.

```php
global $user;

$node = node_load($nid);
$data = array(
  1 => array( $component1_value),
  2 => array($component2_value),
);

$submission = (object) array(
  'nid' => $node->nid,
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'submitted' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'remote_addr' => ip_address(),
  'is_draft' => FALSE,
  'data' => $data,
  'serial' => _webform_service_submission_serial_next_value($node->nid)
);

module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
webform_submission_insert($node, $submission);
webform_submission_send_mail($node, $submission); 

function _webform_service_submission_serial_next_value($nid, $increment = TRUE) {
  if ($increment) {
    db_transaction();
  }
  $next_serial = db_select('webform', 'w')
    ->forUpdate()
    ->fields('w', array('next_serial'))
    ->condition('nid', $nid)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchField();
        
  if ($next_serial && $increment) {
    $increment_amount = 1;
    db_update('webform')->fields(array('next_serial' => $next_serial + $increment_amount))
      ->condition('nid', $nid)
      ->execute();
  }
  return $next_serial;
}
```

Comment: WOW. This was basically a copy and paste operation. I cannot thank you enough for this. I threw this into a test file, ran by `drush scr test.php`, and bam, the webform results tab has another entry. Bounty rewarded.

Comment: I've gotten this to work inside of stright PHP via `drush scr test.php` but the SimpleTest itself is spitting back errors. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150360

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically submit a Drupal form with [drupal_form_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) by passing it a `$form_state` array with its `values` sub-array pre-populated with the data you want to submit. You'll need the form id of the form you're submitting, too, which in the case of a Webform is `webform_client_form_<NODEID>` (of course, replace `<NODEID>` with the node ID of the webform you want to submit).

Comment: I've added the results of doing this in the question above. Basically, I get "`Missing argument 3 for webform_client_form() webform.module: 2268                                                           [warning] Invalid argument supplied for foreach() webform.module:2843`"

Comment: I see you got past that, but have another error. But think you're getting close (disclaimer: I've never done this, I just threw my answer out here since I've used drupal_form_submit for non webform-related purposes and figured it would work here). Try nesting your submitted values in another sub-array, `$form_state['values']['submitted']`. That's the way Webform handles its fields, so maybe your submission isn't passing validation. FWIW, somebody else has gotten this to work: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76865/how-do-i-programatically-submit-a-webform-via-drupal-form-submit.

Comment: Thanks. Although another answer provided a good course,  I upvoted your answer for not only pointing me in a good direction but staying in the conversation. Many, many thanks. Upvote.

Comment: You're welcome, and good to know you got a working solution. Cheers!